# ¿Cómo comprobar si una cadena contiene una palabra específica en PHP?

Tags: php

Consideramos que la variable `$foo` contiene una cadena con valor *hola mundo*. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo se podría hacer una comprobación si `$foo` contiene la palabra *mundo* y lanzar un `echo`?

```
$foo = 'Hola mundo';

if($foo contiene 'mundo') {
  echo 'True';
}
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366730/1983854

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar con la función [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php), la cual te permite buscar la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un substring en un string, es decir, la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un string dentro de otro string.

En caso de no encontrar la posición devolverá `false`.

```
$foo = 'Hola mundo';

if (strpos($foo, 'mundo') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: gracias @Error404, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Además, si te interesa comprobar si existe la palabra independientemente de mayúsculas o minúsculas, usa `stripos`(http://php.net/manual/es/function.stripos.php)

Comment: Si ahora la acepto, es que hasta transcurrido 10min no me deja aceptarla @Error404

Answer (score 5):

La [respuesta de Error404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34948/250) es la mejor (usar [`strpos`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34948/250), [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stripos.php) o [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php)), como alternativa voy a sugerir usar expresiones regulares y [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) que puede servirte en otros casos (por ejemplo si necesitas buscar algún patrón más que una cadena concreta) y que, aunque funcionará en tu caso particular, no es lo recomendable porque será más lento.

Así podrías hacer algo como:

```
$foo = 'Hola mundo'; 

if(preg_match('/mundo/i', $foo)){
    echo 'True';
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, siempre viene bien tener alternativas, en alguna ocasión seguro que me servirá.

Answer (score 5):

Otra opción sería usar la función [strstr(String cadena,String busqueda)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php) **busca la primera aparición de una cadena dentro de otra cadena**,Si encuentra el valor buscado , será ese el valor devuelto caso contrario devolverá cadena vacía. A todo esto aplicando la función [strlen(String cadena)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php) para obtener la longitud de la cadena *(si es mayor que 0 se encuentra)*

```
$foo = 'Hola mundo';
if (strlen(strstr($foo,'mundo'))>0) {
  echo "Se encuentra";
}
```

La función anterior  es sensible a mayúsculas, si desea que no importe  las mayúsculas , usar la función [stristr(String cadena,String busqueda)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stristr.php)

```
$foo = 'Hola mundo';
if (strlen(stristr($foo,'MUNDO'))>0) {
  echo "Se encuentra";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Las funciones [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stripos.php), [`strpos`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34948/250) y [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php) sirven para encontrar **subcadenas**.
Por ejemplo, encontrarían la palabra `"la"` dentro de `"hola mundo"`.

Si se buscan **palabras**, se debe verificar que antes y después de la palabra no haya caracteres alfanuméricos. Utilizando expresiones regulares, la aserción `\b` coincide en estas posiciones.

```php
function contiene_palabra($texto, $palabra){
    return preg_match('*\b' . $palabra . '\b*i', $texto);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/W8OJG5

---

Sólo hay que tener en cuenta que `$palabra` no debería tener ninguno de los siguientes metacaracteres de regex, y podría fallar si los tuviese.

```
 \   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )   [   {
```

Esta es una versión segura:

```php
function contiene_palabra($texto, $palabra){
    return preg_match('*\b' . preg_quote($palabra) . '\b*i', $texto);
}
```

Y, para saber en qué posición se encuentra la palabra:

```php
function contiene_palabra($texto, $palabra){
    if (preg_match('*\b' . preg_quote($palabra) . '\b*i', $texto, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
        return $matches[0][1];
    }
    return -1;  // -1 cuando no se encuentra
}
```

```php
if (($pos = contiene_palabra($texto,$palabra)) >= 0) {
    echo "'$texto' contiene la palabra '$palabra' en la posición $pos.\n";
} else {
    echo "No se encuentra la palabra '$palabra' en '$texto'.\n";
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7Jh4nX

Answer (score 1):

Actualización 2022 y PHP 8.

Otra alternativa es usar [str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-contains.php) (PHP 8.0+). Ver [especificación](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/str_contains).

```
> $foo = 'Hola mundo';
> var_dump(str_contains($foo, 'mundo'));
true
```

Puede trabajar directamente con **multibyte**, por lo que **no** es necesaria *la versión* `mb_*`

```
> $var = 'La casa tiene baño y jardín atrás';
> var_dump(str_contains($var, 'baño y jardín'));
true
```

Es **sensible** a mayúsculas y minúsculas, así que de ser necesario hacer las conversiones previas.

```
> var_dump(str_contains($var, 'Casa'));
false
```

Comment: Haciendo algunas pruebas, puedo constatar que `str_pos()` es tan eficiente como `str_contains()`, pero el hecho de estar dentro de un bloque `if`, posiblemente añada algunos ciclos reloj a los cálculos. Con 100k iteraciones, `str_contains()` tiene una media de `5.62 ms` y el bloque `if | str_pos()` da `6.23 ms`. La ventaja multibyte de `str_contains()` sumado a un código más explícito dan un claro ganador: `str_contains()`, aunque no por mucho.